# Sharepoint2010 powershell assign unique permissions to files in a document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I am trying to assign unique permissions to files in a document library using PowerShell. i.e. iterate through each file in a document library break its role inheritance and assign read permissions to different users for each file.

Below is my powershell script:-

```
$siteCollUrl = http://mysharepointsite
$LibraryName = "Reports"
$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $siteCollUrl;
$spfiles = $spSourceWeb.getfolder($LibraryName).Files
foreach ($file in $spfiles)
{
  $file.BreakRoleInheritance($true) 

}
$spSourceWeb.dispose();
```

But I get an error:-

> Method invocation failed because [System.String] doesn't contain a method named 'BreakRoleInheritance'.

Any pointers on what's the right way of doing it using powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions are on items, and there is a file behind the item. Try this:

```
$siteCollUrl = http://mysharepointsite
$LibraryName = "Reports"
$spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $siteCollUrl;
$list = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$LibraryName]
foreach ($item in $list.Items)
{
  $item.BreakRoleInheritance($true) 
}
$spSourceWeb.Dispose()
```